# Como fazer para que <script></script> não apareça no arquivo HTML. Apareça somente o texto dentro de document.write

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando inserir alguns `scripts` do meu `WHMCS` em uma página `HTML` no meu site, o qual retorna um `document.write(' Texto que irá aparecer ');`, e o texto contido dentro do `document.write` é exibido na página HTML.

*Link do Tutorial*: http://www.whmcs.blog.br/personalizacao/capturando-informacoes-do-produto/

Para funcionar, eu tenho que inserir vários `<script></script>` o que gera muitas requisições.

Gostaria de fazer com que apareça somente:

`<h1>` **Texto que irá aparecer** `</h1>`

Ao invés de:

`<h1><script language="javascript" src=" ">` **Texto que irá aparecer** `</script><h1>`

### Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUwrd/)

(utilizado para exemplo o whmcs da Hostgator)

---

***Tem alguma forma de fazer com que apareça somente o texto ?***

Comment: Apenas com JavaScript, ou pode ser com jQuery também?

Comment: Sim! O que vale é funcionar! :D

Comment: Você poderia implementar um script em PHP para servir de Proxy para a requisição, não é algo muito comum mas pode funcionar. Evitando fazer varias verificações, pedindo os dados somente para uma única URL e ainda pode tratar o resultado.

Comment: @PedroHenrique Você poderia criar uma resposta?
 Obrigado!

Comment: Realmente o comentário do @PedroHenrique faz sentido. Com que frequência esses dados mudam? Você poderia implementar um script e chamá-lo via cronjob para atualizar os dados de tempos em tempos, de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Comment: Eles nunca mudam, acho que CronJob não é um boa alternativa. @Kazzkiq você não conhece o whmcs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando jQuery, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
function removeScripts(el) {

    //Para cada elemento que deve ter o script removido
    $(el).each(function () {
        var i = this;

        //remove os espaços em branco
        var value = ($(i).text()).replace(/\s/g, '');

        //verifica se o texto já foi carregado dentro do elemento
        if (value.length > 0) {

            // se sim, remove a tag script do elemento
            $('script', i).remove();
        } else {

            // se não, dá mais 500ms e tenta denovo
            setTimeout(function () {
                removeScripts(el);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

E para chamar a função:

```
removeScripts('.elementos');
```

Exemplo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/Vk4v6/)**

O que esta função faz é verificar em todos os seletores que você forneceu se existe algum texto (que seria o texto carregado pelo elemento `script`). Caso exista, ele apenas deleta a tag `script`, caso não exista, isto significa que o script ainda não conseguiu carregar o texto, então ele espera 500 milissegundos e tenta novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript é uma linguagem que deve ser executada no cliente, e por isso não é possível ocultar completamente um código javascript. Nesse caso, o recomendado é separar o código javascript do HTML, em um arquivo js. Em seguida, esse arquivo javascript pode ser minificado, sendo transformado em um arquivo mais difícil de ser lido por um ser humano. Um exemplo de site que pode ser utilizado para minificar o seu código javascript pode ser encontrado [aqui](http://javascript-minifier.com/).